# Sublime Text 2 - Not able to create a pop up box for prompt()

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I began using Sublime Text 2 for my Javascript coding and love it. I'm creating a small project that requires input from the user.  Normally, or from previous practice, I was able to write:

var x = prompt("What city do you live in?")
and have the string assigned to the var x

But, when I run this line of code in ST2 I get:

Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: prompt.

I've installed Package Control but can't find a plug-in to address my need.I installed SublimeREPL and that didn't work for me.

Thanks, this is my first question on Stack.  Any comments or assistance is welcomed.

Comment: Are you trying to run javascript in sublime text, when the [language for wirting plugins is python (link to documentation)](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/plugins.html) ?

Comment: True, ST 2 does not natively run JS.  But I followed these directions to create a JS console, and it does work except for a few exceptions i.e I must use debug() in place of console.log()  http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text

Comment: Even then `prompt` is surely not part of javascriptCore nor node.js API, `window.prompt` is a DOM api, meaning it could be used in a web browser window. Same for `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot run javascript in sublime text, the [language to write plugins in python](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/plugins.html),

the SublimeREPL require extra binary to be installed to run Javascript (probably node.js),

and even then the [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) is a browser API, not a javascript function (by default you are running at the `window` level which provide the default method with the need to prefix by the object name)

In conclusion your Javascript console REPL in most case does not have the prompt function/method/API available

Answer (score 0):

I've never used JS to create sublime plugin, but you could use the function `window.show_input_panel`. Have a look at [the sublime text 2 API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html).

Matt